# HDFS_NAMENODE_USER, HDFS_DATANODE_USER & HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER not defined

Tags: hadoop, hadoop3

I am new to hadoop.
I'm trying to install hadoop in my laptop in Pseudo-Distributed mode.
I am running it with root user, but I'm getting the error below.

```
root@debdutta-Lenovo-G50-80:~# $HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/start-dfs.sh
WARNING: HADOOP_PREFIX has been replaced by HADOOP_HOME. Using value of HADOOP_PREFIX.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs namenode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_NAMENODE_USER defined. 
Aborting operation.
Starting datanodes
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs datanode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_DATANODE_USER defined. 
Aborting operation.
Starting secondary namenodes [debdutta-Lenovo-G50-80]
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs secondarynamenode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER defined. Aborting operation.
WARNING: HADOOP_PREFIX has been replaced by  HADOOP_HOME. Using value of HADOOP_PREFIX.
```

Also, I have to run hadoop in root user as hadoop is not able to access ssh service with other user.
How to fix the same?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify how you've installed Hadoop. Are you reading the official documentation?

Comment: below is the link I am following to install hadoop.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/getting-hadoop-and-running

Comment: That article is 4 years old, so that's not Hadoop 3. All of the startup scripts changed

Answer (score 52, accepted):

just do what it asks you:

```
export HDFS_NAMENODE_USER="root"
export HDFS_DATANODE_USER="root"
export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER="root"
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER="root"
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER="root"
```

Comment: It is working. But every time I close the terminal I am losing the values.. I had to rerun all the export command all over again

Comment: Add all these commands in hadoop-env.sh and you will be good to go!

Answer (score 14):

The root cause of this problem,

1. hadoop install for different user and you start yarn service for different user. 
   OR
2. in hadoop config's hadoop-env.sh specified  HDFS_NAMENODE_USER and HDFS_DATANODE_USER user is something else.

Hence we need to correct and make it consistent at every place. So a simple solution of this problem is to edit your `hadoop-env.sh` file and add the user-name for which you want to start the yarn service.  So go ahead and edit `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` by adding the following lines

```
export HDFS_NAMENODE_USER=root
export HDFS_DATANODE_USER=root
export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER=root
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER=root
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER=root
```

Now save and start yarn, hdfs service and check that it works.

Comment: make sure ssh service should up and running and datanode and namenode should be access without password. you can verify by
ssh IPs/HostName

Comment: How can i make datanodes and namenodes accessible without password

Answer (score 3):

Based on on the first warning, `HADOOP_PREFIX`, sounds like you've not defined `HADOOP_HOME` correctly.

This would be done in your `/etc/profile.d`.

`hadoop-env.sh` is where the remainder of those variables are are defined.

Please refer to the [UNIX Shell Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/UnixShellGuide.html)

> hadoop is not able to access ssh service with other user

This has nothing to do with Hadoop itself. It's basic SSH account management. You need to

1. Make the hadoop (and other, like yarn) accounts on all machines of a cluster (see `adduser` command documentation)
2. Copy a passwordless SSH key using `ssh-copy-id hadoop@localhost`, for example

If you don't need distributed mode and just want to use Hadoop locally, you can use a [Mini Cluster](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CLIMiniCluster.html).

The documentation  also recommends making a single node installation before continuing to pseudo distributed

Answer (score 2):

Vim `${HADOOP_HOME}sbin/start-dfs.sh` & `${HADOOP_HOME}sbin/stop-dfs.sh`, then add:

```
HDFS_DATANODE_USER=root
HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER=hdfs 
HDFS_NAMENODE_USER=root 
HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER=root
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your pdsh default rcmd rsh

pdsh -q -w localhost  -- should get something like this

-- DSH-specific options --
Separate stderr/stdout  Yes
Path prepended to cmd   none
Appended to cmd         none
Command:                none
Full program pathname   /usr/bin/pdsh
Remote program path     /usr/bin/pdsh

-- Generic options --
Local username          enock
Local uid               1000
Remote username         enock
Rcmd type               rsh
one ^C will kill pdsh   No
Connect timeout (secs)  10
Command timeout (secs)  0
Fanout                  32
Display hostname labels Yes
Debugging               No

-- Target nodes --
localhost

2. Modify pdsh default rcmd. Add pdsh to bashrc
   nano ~/.bashrc
   -- add this line towards the end
   export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh
   -- update
   source ~/.bashrc

That should solve your problem

C. sbin/start-dfs.sh