# Run hadoop in the Mac OS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I try to set up to run the Hadoop in the Mac OS with `brew`. The steps taken are provided below,

1. install `hadoop` with the command, `$brew install hadoop`
2. Inside the folder `usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/etc/hadoop` and added the commands in the file `hadoop-env.sh`,

   `export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
   export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Finally, the file looks like the following,

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Set Hadoop-specific environment variables here.

##
## THIS FILE ACTS AS THE MASTER FILE FOR ALL HADOOP PROJECTS.
## SETTINGS HERE WILL BE READ BY ALL HADOOP COMMANDS.  THEREFORE,
## ONE CAN USE THIS FILE TO SET YARN, HDFS, AND MAPREDUCE
## CONFIGURATION OPTIONS INSTEAD OF xxx-env.sh.
##
## Precedence rules:
##
## {yarn-env.sh|hdfs-env.sh} > hadoop-env.sh > hard-coded defaults
##
## {YARN_xyz|HDFS_xyz} > HADOOP_xyz > hard-coded defaults
##

# Many of the options here are built from the perspective that users
# may want to provide OVERWRITING values on the command line.
# For example:
#
#  JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/testing hdfs dfs -ls
#
# Therefore, the vast majority (BUT NOT ALL!) of these defaults
# are configured for substitution and not append.  If append
# is preferable, modify this file accordingly.

###
# Generic settings for HADOOP
###

# Technically, the only required environment variable is JAVA_HOME.
# All others are optional.  However, the defaults are probably not
# preferred.  Many sites configure these options outside of Hadoop,
# such as in /etc/profile.d

# The java implementation to use. By default, this environment
# variable is REQUIRED on ALL platforms except OS X!
# export JAVA_HOME=

# Location of Hadoop.  By default, Hadoop will attempt to determine
# this location based upon its execution path.
# export HADOOP_HOME=

# Location of Hadoop's configuration information.  i.e., where this
# file is living. If this is not defined, Hadoop will attempt to
# locate it based upon its execution path.
#
# NOTE: It is recommend that this variable not be set here but in
# /etc/profile.d or equivalent.  Some options (such as
# --config) may react strangely otherwise.
#
# export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop

# The maximum amount of heap to use (Java -Xmx).  If no unit
# is provided, it will be converted to MB.  Daemons will
# prefer any Xmx setting in their respective _OPT variable.
# There is no default; the JVM will autoscale based upon machine
# memory size.
# export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE_MAX=

# The minimum amount of heap to use (Java -Xms).  If no unit
# is provided, it will be converted to MB.  Daemons will
# prefer any Xms setting in their respective _OPT variable.
# There is no default; the JVM will autoscale based upon machine
# memory size.
# export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE_MIN=

# Enable extra debugging of Hadoop's JAAS binding, used to set up
# Kerberos security.
# export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true

# Extra Java runtime options for all Hadoop commands. We don't support
# IPv6 yet/still, so by default the preference is set to IPv4.
# export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
# For Kerberos debugging, an extended option set logs more invormation
# export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Dsun.security.spnego.debug"
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home"


# Some parts of the shell code may do special things dependent upon
# the operating system.  We have to set this here. See the next
# section as to why....
export HADOOP_OS_TYPE=${HADOOP_OS_TYPE:-$(uname -s)}


# Under certain conditions, Java on OS X will throw SCDynamicStore errors
# in the system logs.
# See HADOOP-8719 for more information.  If one needs Kerberos
# support on OS X, one will want to change/remove this extra bit.
case ${HADOOP_OS_TYPE} in
  Darwin*)
    export HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.realm= "
    export HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.kdc= "
    export HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.conf= "
  ;;
esac

# Extra Java runtime options for some Hadoop commands
# and clients (i.e., hdfs dfs -blah).  These get appended to HADOOP_OPTS for
# such commands.  In most cases, # this should be left empty and
# let users supply it on the command line.
# export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS=""

#
# A note about classpaths.
#
# By default, Apache Hadoop overrides Java's CLASSPATH
# environment variable.  It is configured such
# that it sarts out blank with new entries added after passing
# a series of checks (file/dir exists, not already listed aka
# de-deduplication).  During de-depulication, wildcards and/or
# directories are *NOT* expanded to keep it simple. Therefore,
# if the computed classpath has two specific mentions of
# awesome-methods-1.0.jar, only the first one added will be seen.
# If two directories are in the classpath that both contain
# awesome-methods-1.0.jar, then Java will pick up both versions.

# An additional, custom CLASSPATH. Site-wide configs should be
# handled via the shellprofile functionality, utilizing the
# hadoop_add_classpath function for greater control and much
# harder for apps/end-users to accidentally override.
# Similarly, end users should utilize ${HOME}/.hadooprc .
# This variable should ideally only be used as a short-cut,
# interactive way for temporary additions on the command line.
# export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="/some/cool/path/on/your/machine"

# Should HADOOP_CLASSPATH be first in the official CLASSPATH?
# export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST="yes"

# If HADOOP_USE_CLIENT_CLASSLOADER is set, the classpath along
# with the main jar are handled by a separate isolated
# client classloader when 'hadoop jar', 'yarn jar', or 'mapred job'
# is utilized. If it is set, HADOOP_CLASSPATH and
# HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST are ignored.
# export HADOOP_USE_CLIENT_CLASSLOADER=true

# HADOOP_CLIENT_CLASSLOADER_SYSTEM_CLASSES overrides the default definition of
# system classes for the client classloader when HADOOP_USE_CLIENT_CLASSLOADER
# is enabled. Names ending in '.' (period) are treated as package names, and
# names starting with a '-' are treated as negative matches. For example,
# export HADOOP_CLIENT_CLASSLOADER_SYSTEM_CLASSES="-org.apache.hadoop.UserClass,java.,javax.,org.apache.hadoop."

# Enable optional, bundled Hadoop features
# This is a comma delimited list.  It may NOT be overridden via .hadooprc
# Entries may be added/removed as needed.
# export HADOOP_OPTIONAL_TOOLS="hadoop-openstack,hadoop-aliyun,hadoop-azure,hadoop-azure-datalake,hadoop-aws,hadoop-kafka"

###
# Options for remote shell connectivity
###

# There are some optional components of hadoop that allow for
# command and control of remote hosts.  For example,
# start-dfs.sh will attempt to bring up all NNs, DNS, etc.

# Options to pass to SSH when one of the "log into a host and
# start/stop daemons" scripts is executed
# export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=10s"

# The built-in ssh handler will limit itself to 10 simultaneous connections.
# For pdsh users, this sets the fanout size ( -f )
# Change this to increase/decrease as necessary.
# export HADOOP_SSH_PARALLEL=10

# Filename which contains all of the hosts for any remote execution
# helper scripts # such as workers.sh, start-dfs.sh, etc.
# export HADOOP_WORKERS="${HADOOP_CONF_DIR}/workers"

###
# Options for all daemons
###
#

#
# Many options may also be specified as Java properties.  It is
# very common, and in many cases, desirable, to hard-set these
# in daemon _OPTS variables.  Where applicable, the appropriate
# Java property is also identified.  Note that many are re-used
# or set differently in certain contexts (e.g., secure vs
# non-secure)
#

# Where (primarily) daemon log files are stored.
# ${HADOOP_HOME}/logs by default.
# Java property: hadoop.log.dir
# export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/logs

# A string representing this instance of hadoop. $USER by default.
# This is used in writing log and pid files, so keep that in mind!
# Java property: hadoop.id.str
# export HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=$USER

# How many seconds to pause after stopping a daemon
# export HADOOP_STOP_TIMEOUT=5

# Where pid files are stored.  /tmp by default.
# export HADOOP_PID_DIR=/tmp

# Default log4j setting for interactive commands
# Java property: hadoop.root.logger
# export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=INFO,console

# Default log4j setting for daemons spawned explicitly by
# --daemon option of hadoop, hdfs, mapred and yarn command.
# Java property: hadoop.root.logger
# export HADOOP_DAEMON_ROOT_LOGGER=INFO,RFA

# Default log level and output location for security-related messages.
# You will almost certainly want to change this on a per-daemon basis via
# the Java property (i.e., -Dhadoop.security.logger=foo). (Note that the
# defaults for the NN and 2NN override this by default.)
# Java property: hadoop.security.logger
# export HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER=INFO,NullAppender

# Default process priority level
# Note that sub-processes will also run at this level!
# export HADOOP_NICENESS=0

# Default name for the service level authorization file
# Java property: hadoop.policy.file
# export HADOOP_POLICYFILE="hadoop-policy.xml"

#
# NOTE: this is not used by default!  <-----
# You can define variables right here and then re-use them later on.
# For example, it is common to use the same garbage collection settings
# for all the daemons.  So one could define:
#
# export HADOOP_GC_SETTINGS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"
#
# .. and then use it as per the b option under the namenode.

###
# Secure/privileged execution
###

#
# Out of the box, Hadoop uses jsvc from Apache Commons to launch daemons
# on privileged ports.  This functionality can be replaced by providing
# custom functions.  See hadoop-functions.sh for more information.
#

# The jsvc implementation to use. Jsvc is required to run secure datanodes
# that bind to privileged ports to provide authentication of data transfer
# protocol.  Jsvc is not required if SASL is configured for authentication of
# data transfer protocol using non-privileged ports.
# export JSVC_HOME=/usr/bin

#
# This directory contains pids for secure and privileged processes.
#export HADOOP_SECURE_PID_DIR=${HADOOP_PID_DIR}

#
# This directory contains the logs for secure and privileged processes.
# Java property: hadoop.log.dir
# export HADOOP_SECURE_LOG=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}

#
# When running a secure daemon, the default value of HADOOP_IDENT_STRING
# ends up being a bit bogus.  Therefore, by default, the code will
# replace HADOOP_IDENT_STRING with HADOOP_xx_SECURE_USER.  If one wants
# to keep HADOOP_IDENT_STRING untouched, then uncomment this line.
# export HADOOP_SECURE_IDENT_PRESERVE="true"

###
# NameNode specific parameters
###

# Default log level and output location for file system related change
# messages. For non-namenode daemons, the Java property must be set in
# the appropriate _OPTS if one wants something other than INFO,NullAppender
# Java property: hdfs.audit.logger
# export HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER=INFO,NullAppender

# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the NameNode.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# a) Set JMX options
# export HDFS_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1026"
#
# b) Set garbage collection logs
# export HDFS_NAMENODE_OPTS="${HADOOP_GC_SETTINGS} -Xloggc:${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/gc-rm.log-$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M')"
#
# c) ... or set them directly
# export HDFS_NAMENODE_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/gc-rm.log-$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M')"

# this is the default:
# export HDFS_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS"

###
# SecondaryNameNode specific parameters
###
# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the SecondaryNameNode.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# This is the default:
# export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS"

###
# DataNode specific parameters
###
# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the DataNode.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# This is the default:
# export HDFS_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=ERROR,RFAS"

# On secure datanodes, user to run the datanode as after dropping privileges.
# This **MUST** be uncommented to enable secure HDFS if using privileged ports
# to provide authentication of data transfer protocol.  This **MUST NOT** be
# defined if SASL is configured for authentication of data transfer protocol
# using non-privileged ports.
# This will replace the hadoop.id.str Java property in secure mode.
# export HDFS_DATANODE_SECURE_USER=hdfs

# Supplemental options for secure datanodes
# By default, Hadoop uses jsvc which needs to know to launch a
# server jvm.
# export HDFS_DATANODE_SECURE_EXTRA_OPTS="-jvm server"

###
# NFS3 Gateway specific parameters
###
# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the NFS3 Gateway.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# export HDFS_NFS3_OPTS=""

# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the Hadoop portmapper.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# export HDFS_PORTMAP_OPTS="-Xmx512m"

# Supplemental options for priviliged gateways
# By default, Hadoop uses jsvc which needs to know to launch a
# server jvm.
# export HDFS_NFS3_SECURE_EXTRA_OPTS="-jvm server"

# On privileged gateways, user to run the gateway as after dropping privileges
# This will replace the hadoop.id.str Java property in secure mode.
# export HDFS_NFS3_SECURE_USER=nfsserver

###
# ZKFailoverController specific parameters
###
# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the ZKFailoverController.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# export HDFS_ZKFC_OPTS=""

###
# QuorumJournalNode specific parameters
###
# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the QuorumJournalNode.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# export HDFS_JOURNALNODE_OPTS=""

###
# HDFS Balancer specific parameters
###
# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the HDFS Balancer.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# export HDFS_BALANCER_OPTS=""

###
# HDFS Mover specific parameters
###
# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the HDFS Mover.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# export HDFS_MOVER_OPTS=""

###
# Router-based HDFS Federation specific parameters
# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the RBF Routers.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# export HDFS_DFSROUTER_OPTS=""
###

###
# Advanced Users Only!
###

#
# When building Hadoop, one can add the class paths to the commands
# via this special env var:
# export HADOOP_ENABLE_BUILD_PATHS="true"

#
# To prevent accidents, shell commands be (superficially) locked
# to only allow certain users to execute certain subcommands.
# It uses the format of (command)_(subcommand)_USER.
#


# For example, to limit who can execute the namenode command,
# export HDFS_NAMENODE_USER=hdfs
```

3. configure HDFS address and port number, open `core-site.xml`, input following content in `<configuration></configuration>` tag,

   `<configuration>
       <property>
           <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
           <value>/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp</value>
           <description>A base for other temporary directories. 
           </description>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>fs.default.name</name>
           <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
       </property>
   </configuration>`
4. Configure jobtracker address and port number in `map-reduce`, first `sudo cp mapred-site.xml mapred-site.xml.template` to make a copy of `mapred-site.xml`, and open `mapred-site.xml`, add

   ```
   <configuration>
     <property>
       <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
       <value>localhost:8021</value>
      </property>
   </configuration>
   ```
5. Set HDFS default backup, the default value is 3, we should change to 1, open `hdfs-site.xml`, add

   `<configuration>
       <property>
           <name>dfs.replication</name>
           <value>1</value>
       </property>
   </configuration>`
6. Format the installed HDFS first, executing command `hdfs namenode -format`

At the end of the process, I enter inside `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/sbin` and try to run hadoop,

```
$ ./start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Starting datanodes
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Starting secondary namenodes [macs-MacBook-Pro.local]
macs-MacBook-Pro.local: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
2018-08-12 17:31:38,503 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

It appears I had to run as root and tried with

```
$sudo ./start-dfs.sh

Starting namenodes on [localhost]
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs namenode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_NAMENODE_USER defined. Aborting operation.
Starting datanodes
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs datanode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_DATANODE_USER defined. Aborting operation.
Starting secondary namenodes [macs-MacBook-Pro.local]
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs secondarynamenode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER defined. Aborting operation.
2018-08-12 17:48:27,172 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I felt the issue is with no `HDFS_NAMENODE_USER` defined. I looked into the Google and added the following file at the end of file `hadoop-env.sh`

```
export HDFS_NAMENODE_USER="root"
export HDFS_DATANODE_USER="root"
export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER="root"
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER="root"
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER="root"
```

Later, I again run `$sudo ./start-dfs.sh` and get the outout,

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: `  done < <(for text in "${input[@]}"; do'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 70: hadoop_deprecate_envvar: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: hadoop_bootstrap: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 104: hadoop_parse_args: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 105: shift: : numeric argument required
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 244: hadoop_need_reexec: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 252: hadoop_verify_user_perm: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 213: hadoop_validate_classname: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 214: hadoop_exit_with_usage: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 263: hadoop_add_client_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 270: hadoop_subcommand_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 273: hadoop_generic_java_subcmd_handler: command not found
Starting datanodes
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: `  done < <(for text in "${input[@]}"; do'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 70: hadoop_deprecate_envvar: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: hadoop_bootstrap: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 104: hadoop_parse_args: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 105: shift: : numeric argument required
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 244: hadoop_need_reexec: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 252: hadoop_verify_user_perm: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 213: hadoop_validate_classname: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 214: hadoop_exit_with_usage: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 263: hadoop_add_client_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 270: hadoop_subcommand_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 273: hadoop_generic_java_subcmd_handler: command not found
Starting secondary namenodes [macs-MacBook-Pro.local]
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: `  done < <(for text in "${input[@]}"; do'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 70: hadoop_deprecate_envvar: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: hadoop_bootstrap: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 104: hadoop_parse_args: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 105: shift: : numeric argument required
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 244: hadoop_need_reexec: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 252: hadoop_verify_user_perm: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 213: hadoop_validate_classname: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 214: hadoop_exit_with_usage: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 263: hadoop_add_client_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 270: hadoop_subcommand_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 273: hadoop_generic_java_subcmd_handler: command not found
2018-08-12 17:49:46,943 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

At this point, I'm trackless about what is needed to be done. I appreciate a suggestion from experienced Hadoop developers. I use `High Sierra OS` and have Java 8 installed in the machine.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Earlier, I checked this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129029/hdfs-namenode-user-hdfs-datanode-user-hdfs-secondarynamenode-user-not-defined/50016867

Comment: I followed the tutorial from the web site: https://isaacchanghau.github.io/post/install_hadoop_mac/

Comment: That post uses Hadoop 2... Hadoop 3 changed some things... Besides that, that tutorial is wrong as the job tracker doesn't even exist, so it doesn't need configured. And `fs.default.name` is a deprecated property name... Please refer to the official documentation http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#YARN_on_a_Single_Node

Comment: I will try to configure along the official page. Btw, do you know any tutorial for Hadoop 3 setup in Mac OS?

Comment: I don't typically run Hadoop on Mac outside of Docker or VMs only for testing, so no I don't know any

Comment: Is that Linux VM is better choice for Hadoop? I have Debian installed so I may try there too

Comment: Well, both Hortonworks and Cloudera offer pre-installed VMs, and that's how I learned Hadoop

Comment: I will check there website and update here

Comment: hi @cricket_007, I finally managed to set up the Hadoop in the Mac OS and manage to run the word count in the Cluster

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Hadoop Setup In The Pseudo-distributed Mode (Mac OS)**

A. `brew search hadoop`

B. Go to hadoop base directory, `usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0_1/libexec/etc/hadoop`  and under this folder, it requires to modify these files:

(i). `hadoop-env.sh`

Change from

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
```

to

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

(ii). `core-site.xml`

Then configure HDFS address and port number, open core-site.xml, input following content in configuration tag

```
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
 <configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp</value>
        <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

(iii). `mapred-site.xml`

Configure MapReduce to use YARN, first copy `mapred-site.xml.template` to `mapred-site.xml`, and open `mapred-site.xml`, add

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
        <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/Users/Masser/hadoop</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
        <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/Users/Masser/hadoop</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
        <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/Users/Masser/hadoop</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

(iv). hdfs-site.xml

Set HDFS default backup, the default value is 3, we should change to 1, open hdfs-site.xml, add

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

(v). `yarn-site.xml`

To walk through the `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException`: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist, we need to modify the file,

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

C. Setup a pass-phraseless SSH and Authorize the generate SSH keys:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' 
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Finally, Enable Remote Login in (System Preference->Sharing), Just click “remote login”.

Test ssh at localhost: It should not prompt for a password

```
$ ssh localhost

Last login: Fri Aug 17 12:08:08 2018
```

D. Format the distributed file system with the below command before starting the Hadoop daemons. So that we can put our data sources into the hdfs file system while performing the map-reduce job

```
$ hdfs namenode -format
```

E. We need to provide aliases to start and stop Hadoop Daemons. For this purpose, we edit `~/.bash_profile` and add

```
alias hstart="/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0_1/sbin/start-all.sh"
alias hstop="/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0_1/sbin/stop-all.sh"

$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

SETUP CHECK

i.  Start hadoop using alias

```
$ hstart
```

ii. Hadoop NameNode started on port 9870 default. Access your server on port 9870:

http://localhost:9870/

iii. Access port 8042 for getting the information about the cluster and all applications:

http://localhost:8042/

iv. Access port 9864 to get details about your Hadoop node:

http://localhost:9864/datanode.html

v. Stop hadoop using alias

```
$ hstop
```

Comment: Overall, looks okay, but JAVA_HOME didn't need changing and HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME doesn't look right (hadoop might start, but it'll fail to run a MapReduce job)

Comment: I changed it after the error log and runs fine the MapReduce job (locally and cluster in pseudo distributed mode)

Comment: I have fresh macOS and `brew hadoop` installs, and there is no line `export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"` in `hadoop-env.sh` (3.1.2) ... and the most similar line is commented out.  Any guidance?

Comment: This will work as well: `export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"`