# How to run hadoop commands on mac to avoid error "Command not found"?

Tags: macos, hadoop

I have installed hadoop on my mac using [this](https://medium.com/@gnakan/getting-started-with-apache-hbase-31182755331) link and hence, my file structure and content is as mentioned in the blog post. Going to the final part of step i), I run the command: `sudo sh start-all.sh` and that generates errors:

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: `  done < <(for text in "${input[@]}"; do'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 70: hadoop_deprecate_envvar: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: hadoop_bootstrap: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 104: hadoop_parse_args: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 105: shift: : numeric argument required
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 244: hadoop_need_reexec: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 252: hadoop_verify_user_perm: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 213: hadoop_validate_classname: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 214: hadoop_exit_with_usage: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 263: hadoop_add_client_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 270: hadoop_subcommand_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 273: hadoop_generic_java_subcmd_handler: command not found
Starting datanodes
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: `  done < <(for text in "${input[@]}"; do'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 70: hadoop_deprecate_envvar: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: hadoop_bootstrap: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 104: hadoop_parse_args: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 105: shift: : numeric argument required
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 244: hadoop_need_reexec: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 252: hadoop_verify_user_perm: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 213: hadoop_validate_classname: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 214: hadoop_exit_with_usage: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 263: hadoop_add_client_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 270: hadoop_subcommand_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 273: hadoop_generic_java_subcmd_handler: command not found
Starting secondary namenodes [Bigdaddy-MacBook-Air-3.local]
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: `  done < <(for text in "${input[@]}"; do'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 70: hadoop_deprecate_envvar: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: hadoop_bootstrap: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 104: hadoop_parse_args: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 105: shift: : numeric argument required
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 244: hadoop_need_reexec: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 252: hadoop_verify_user_perm: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 213: hadoop_validate_classname: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 214: hadoop_exit_with_usage: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 263: hadoop_add_client_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 270: hadoop_subcommand_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 273: hadoop_generic_java_subcmd_handler: command not found
2019-01-13 02:00:00,227 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: `  done < <(for text in "${input[@]}"; do'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 70: hadoop_deprecate_envvar: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: hadoop_bootstrap: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 104: hadoop_parse_args: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 105: shift: : numeric argument required
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 265: hadoop_need_reexec: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 273: hadoop_verify_user_perm: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/yarn: line 232: hadoop_validate_classname: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/yarn: line 233: hadoop_exit_with_usage: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 293: hadoop_add_client_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 300: hadoop_subcommand_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 303: hadoop_generic_java_subcmd_handler: command not found
Starting nodemanagers
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 398: `  done < <(for text in "${input[@]}"; do'
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 70: hadoop_deprecate_envvar: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: hadoop_bootstrap: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 104: hadoop_parse_args: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 105: shift: : numeric argument required
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 265: hadoop_need_reexec: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 273: hadoop_verify_user_perm: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/yarn: line 232: hadoop_validate_classname: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/yarn: line 233: hadoop_exit_with_usage: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 293: hadoop_add_client_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 300: hadoop_subcommand_opts: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 303: hadoop_generic_java_subcmd_handler: command not found
```

I have followed posts on stackoverflow and hence found few:
1. [Run hadoop in the Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808588/run-hadoop-in-the-mac-os)

Comment: I  have same issue